# Tensorflow: Reading binary files of varying length?

Tags: tensorflow

I'm trying to read binary files that content information of a 3D scene stored as 19 floats followed by a varying number of uint32 values. Since the scene is stored in Run-length encoding (RLE), every binary file has a different size.

Is it possible to read that kind of data using tensorflow?

The equivalent in Matlab looks like this:

```
filename    = 'myFile.bin';

fid = fopen(filename,'r');
vox_origin = fread(fid,3,'float');
camera_poses = fread(fid,16,'float');
labels = fread(fid,'uint32'); % Labels are saved in RLE 
fclose(fid);

value = labels(1:2:end);
value_iter = labels(2:2:end);
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know any mechanism for this provided by Tensorflow. This is a very basic functionality that you should be able to easily implement or use something like this https://gist.github.com/nvictus/66627b580c13068589957d6ab0919e66. Tensorflow works with numpy arrays.